# Disk usage is increasing with puppeteer - chromium installed using snap

Tags: ubuntu, puppeteer, chromium, snap

I have installed chromium using `snap install chromium` on my Ubuntu server with Arm cpu because when I wanted to install puppeteer using npm it throwed errors, I set `PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH` to `/snap/bin/chromium` and it's working fine. But my problem is that disk space on the vps is getting full, when the usage is really high (more than 95%), I do `snap remove chromium`, `snap install chromium` and `reboot`. After reboot the disk usage is normal again (around 35%). The disk has 50 GB. What is causing that? Aren't browser data removed when I close it using `browser.close()`? Or what could be the reason that this cleans the disk space?

Comment: Run "du" and find out where the space is going ...

Comment: I've had the same problem. It appeared all the space was used by /tmp/snap.chromium and millions of /tmp/puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXX. I am not sure yet how ot disable that behavior.

Comment: did you find any solution?